# Excel VBA Data Source changing URL

Tags: excel, vba, api

I'm using Excel Connection Query to get data, however, I need to change the URL in the as can be seen in the attached image.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQpB.jpg)

how do I access this field in VBA to change just the tracking data? Ive tried to record a macro but i can only seem to refresh it ie;
ActiveWorkbook.Connections( _
                       "Query - tracker").Refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2016 then you can access your query from VBA, check [This](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1) and [This](http://excelunplugged.com/2018/01/23/modifying-power-query-m-code-with-vba/) URLs

The following is my way to do that:-

1- Get the "Formula" of the Target query (by Query name; in my example = "Testing01"), Use

```
myStr = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("Testing01").Formula
```

2- Change "myStr" (to point to your new URL), you can use "Replace" function for example.

3- Write back the Modified String to the Query:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("Testing01").Formula = myStr
```

4- Refresh your Connections

```
For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
  conn.Refresh
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am going to check it now.